# using testFlight i got my application crash log but don't know what went wrong

Tags: ios5, ios4, crash-reports

I have one application and in beta testing i got my application crash but i am not able to understand what is wrong with it, can you suggest me where to look, Thanks :)

```
0 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x00189642 testflight_backtrace + 142
1 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x0018a1d0 TFSignalHandler + 212
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3174872e _sigtramp + 42
3 UIKit 0x362f2aa0 -[UITableView dealloc] + 56
4 CoreFoundation 0x317b5c42 -[NSObject(NSObject) release] + 30
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3125d50c objc_setProperty_non_gc + 120
6 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31255046 objc_setProperty + 26
7 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x001051c8 -[TNTScenarioViewController setScenarioTable:] (TNTScenarioViewController.m:15)
8 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x00103610 -[TNTScenarioViewController viewDidUnload] (TNTScenarioViewController.m:160)
9 UIKit 0x362a9a28 -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 172
10 UIKit 0x362b96b8 -[UIViewController unloadViewIfReloadable] + 16
11 UIKit 0x3630012c -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 40
12 UIKit 0x3630014c -[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] + 16
13 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x00102682 -[TNTScenarioViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] (TNTScenarioViewController.m:40)
14 UIKit 0x36300162 -[UIViewController _didReceiveMemoryWarning:] + 14
15 Foundation 0x3113f182 _nsnote_callback + 142
16 CoreFoundation 0x3182020e __CFXNotificationPost_old + 402
17 CoreFoundation 0x317baeea _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 118
18 Foundation 0x3113c5d2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 70
19 Foundation 0x3113e1c0 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 24
20 UIKit 0x362d6360 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 48
21 UIKit 0x362d6d82 -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 126
22 UIKit 0x362d4506 _memoryStatusChanged + 42
23 CoreFoundation 0x31820d68 __CFNotificationCenterDarwinCallBack + 24
24 CoreFoundation 0x3181dbde __CFMachPortPerform + 210
25 CoreFoundation 0x31828a96 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
26 CoreFoundation 0x3182a83e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
27 CoreFoundation 0x3182b60c __CFRunLoopRun + 520
28 CoreFoundation 0x317bbec2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
29 CoreFoundation 0x317bbdca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
30 GraphicsServices 0x336d641e GSEventRunModal + 114
31 GraphicsServices 0x336d64ca GSEventRun + 62
32 UIKit 0x361abd68 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
33 UIKit 0x361a9806 UIApplicationMain + 670
34 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x000edb68 main (main.m:14)
35 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1 0x000edb27 start + 39
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of a stack trace?  What you are looking at are the lines of code execution from the crash (0) back to a recent frame entry.  As such, this is referred to as a 'back trace' since it goes backwards from the point that the code stopped executing.

I have no knowledge of your code, but you can see from line 14 of the back trace that you received a low memory warning.  This warning caused a chain of unload events, including a deallocation of a UITableView (line 3).

This is immediately followed by the _sigtramp, which probably indicates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  My guess, without seeing the rest of your code, is that you are accessing something that has been released by the low memory unload situation.

Comment: That was very helpful, i don't know much about stack trace but i will try to learn and understand what is going wrong. Thanks you very much